# Windows port of cdb, TinyCDB

Tags: windows, database, constants, port, cdb

Could you recommend Windows port of CDB, TinyCDB ?

TinyCDB does not compile on Windows and requires

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'unistd.h': No such file or directory
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'nss.h': No such file or directory
```

I read that adding O_BINARY flag and #include  fixes it but I think there must be some tested port. I googling does not return any project so far.

Thanks
Max

Comment: Somebody has to be first.  That could be you.

Comment: I have found C++ port that looks to be cross platform http://www.chokkan.org/software/cdbpp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found C++ port that looks to be cross platform http://chokkan.org/software/cdbpp